# Is there a way to completly reinstall Kdenlive so the settings are wiped?

Tags: linux-mint, kdenlive

I am running Linux Mint 19 and recently installed Kdenlive. The install went perfectly normal until I started the program and tried to see if I could find a dark mode. I went to Settings,then Themes and clicked on  a button that said something along that line IIRC. But after I did click it. Whenever I'd click on of the things on the menu bar,the list it would show would be completely black. Even when I right click anywhere else,the list it brings up is completely black as well. I also messed up even more by accidently disabling the menu bar and so I have no idea how to bring it back and from there,disable this "dark mode". I've tried uninstalling Kdenlive both through terminal by typing "sudo apt-get --purge remove kdenlive" and also right clicking the shortcut and uninstalling it that way. But even doing that,the reinstalled one still has these broken settings. Is there anyway I can reset to default settings for this? Or a way to completly uninstall it so the reinstalled one doesn't have these settings? Thanks.

[what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gs1WF.png)

Answer (score 1):

User settings are *not part of* the package; they are stored in your home directory and won't be affected by reinstalling it at system level.

You'll want to just remove [these files](https://community.kde.org/Kdenlive/Configuration) instead:

```
~/.config/kdenliverc
~/.config/session/kdenlive_*
~/.cache/kdenlive
~/.local/share/kdenlive
~/.local/share/stalefiles/kdenlive
~/.local/share/kxmlgui5/kdenlive/kdenliveui.rc
```

Comment: God bless you. I was trying to fix it myself for like a solid 40 minutes. It never crossed my mind that the configs would be in hidden files lol. Looking back at the menu now. It looks like I went to styles and picked `bb10dark`